# how to arrange the list items using column count?

Tags: javascript, css

i want to arrange the list items using column count or any other alternative.  i want to limit the rows in this code `<li>` may vary

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
</ul>
```

and css is

```
ul {
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 20px;
 }
```

Desired output

```
a                     g
b                     h
c                     i
d                     j
e                     k
f
1
2
```

Comment: where is use  your (1,2 ) ?? inside your output.

Comment: well, I'd do it using php and grid system, columns are still not very usable (check known issues): http://caniuse.com#search=column

Comment: problem is when i use column count:3 in css it divides whole <li> in three equal parts and div remains empty at the bottom , so i want this to go to bottom first then starts from second column. did you get

Comment: @moped how do i do that can you please give some example.. ?

Comment: for example by using `array_slice`

Comment: you purpose is like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my two-pennies: [example in js](https://jsfiddle.net/5e0bLsgf/1/)

just using some jquery to move items in an intermediate div with `float: left`

Comment: @Carosi every thing is fine but when i am putting this in my actual code its not returning the desired result https://jsfiddle.net/5e0bLsgf/1/

Comment: are you still using ul and li?

Comment: it's not working here as i put the same code https://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_chauhan90/38d9arv8/1/

Comment: you have to include jquery, do it by option of the javascript window

Comment: how to add jquery in JSfiddle :( :(:(

Comment: can you post a link to your page?

Comment: post the code please, i cannot help you if i don't see the problem

Comment: Excluding the css to improve, this works with ul and li. I have used the class Cont as selector for the ul, as in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/rcpb8wyd/1/

Comment: @Carosi i want to fit this code into http://pastie.org/10920450#3 but not able to fit this .. can you please help me out .....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (which won't give you the one-and-a-half columns you have, though...):

```
ul {
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

As you wrote, the content will always be distributed as evenly as possible in the columns. A height setting will only influence the result if it's smaller than what fits into the number of given columns. See this codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbVgxb

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.ulist {
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    height: 200px;
}
li {
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulist">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to make the first column fill first, then the second, ... etc:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 190px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
</ul>
```